# ZF2 Testing: Failed asserting response code "302", actual status code is "500"

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am implementing PHPUnit tests for an `AuthenticationController`. When I test the `/logout` route:

```
public function testLogoutActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->dispatch('/logout');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(302);

    $this->assertModuleName('Main');
    $this->assertControllerName('Main\Controller\Authentication');
    $this->assertControllerClass('AuthenticationController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('logout');
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) MainTest\Controller\AuthenticationControllerTest::testLogoutActionCanBeAccessed
Failed asserting response code "302", actual status code is "500"
```

The logout code is the following:

```
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->loginLogoutService->logout();

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
}
```

and

```
public function logout() {
    $this->authservice->getStorage()->forgetMe();
    $this->authservice->clearIdentity();
}
```

and

```
$this->authservice = new AuthenticationService();
```

When I debug my app step-by-step, the `$actionResponse` status code is 302 and the application works fine. 500 is internal server error. I have no idea where it is coming from.

Anyone has some idea?

**P.S.**:

```
public function setUp()
{

    $this->setApplicationConfig(
        include '/../../../../../config/application.config.php'
    );
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Comment: Try adding `protected $traceError = true;` at the top of your test class. It should provide a better error response for you.

Comment: I just did, but the error message is exactly the same. It does not provide more information.

Comment: Have you included the application config in the test set-up? If you remove the assertion for the status code, do the others work?

Comment: Yes, see my question update. The other route tests work. Only this one fails.

Comment: What update? Can you show me your `setUp()` function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to click on save.

Comment: what do your server logs say?

Comment: @Micheal Nothing in the error logs... It is a mystery...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem too. In my case in one of previous tests session was already started and consequently headers was sent. As a result I've got such side effect. One of solutions is run such tests separately from each other. Or maybe better use another testing tool like selenium for test like this.