# Where are the built-in PHP server logs?

Tags: php, logging, webserver, built-in

Where can I find the built-in PHP server logs on Windows 10, knowing that my PHP installation is in `c:\php` and that I am running my application from NetBeans? Are these logs always created? This question follows another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394839/zf2-testing-failed-asserting-response-code-302-actual-status-code-is-500) .

I have seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122267/php-built-in-server-error-log-location), but there is no `c:\php\logs\` on my laptop.

**Update**

I have set the following in my `php.ini`:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = "c:\php\logs\php_errors.log"
```

I have added the following line in my `layout.phtml`:

```
    <?php
    echo ini_get('error_log');
    syslog ( LOG_ERR , "Poupoupidou" );
    ?>
```

This displays `c:\php\logs\php_errors.log`, but I do not see the log file in this directory.

**Update II**

Some logs have been generated in `c:\php\logs\` for a separate issue.

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` or the `php.ini` file maybe ?

Comment: are you using localhost environment? If yes then which one (WAMP or XAMPP)?

Comment: I am not using WAMP or XAMMP, just NetBeans.

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile - Found after Googling "where are logs located in netbeans?"

Comment: *"but there is no c:\php\logs\ on my laptop"* - Because you didn't install PHP?

Comment: PHP is installed on my PC (in c:\php).

Comment: Then see the link I found and maybe search for "logs" in your PC. I don't know Netbeans, but I do know Google ;-)

Comment: I did, but it does not contain any logs related to PHP.

Comment: Where is your PHP error log defined in php.ini? Maybe you need to create that directory. Also probably want to make sure error reporting is also enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that out using:

```
echo ini_get('error_log');
```

Comment: It returns nothing (empty string).

Comment: This means that you need to modify the php.ini and assign a value to it - a filename. Make sure that the file is writable by the web server.

Comment: Tried (see my question update), but nothing is generated. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `syslog()`? (You are using the wrong function, in the wrong way).. If you want to trigger an error log message trough PHP's error log facilities use [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.trigger-error.php)

Comment: Modifying the php.ini setting to set a proper directory and enabling error logs solved the issue.